# Azure App Service applicationHost.config Set server variable is working but not working

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

We are trying to rewrite the "host" header given a header of "X-CF-ORIGIN" - this works locally, however, in the app service, all logging indicates it has worked but we don't seem to see the effect.

We expect to get a 500 error for an incorrect HOST header, however, the site resolves as if the host header has not been changed.

Also, our XDT transform indicates it has worked (see below).

[This was initially raised on Kudu Github](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2627) but have been directed to here for Azure App Service IIS questions.

**A code example:** 
https://github.com/Workshop2/webforms-host-header-rewrite-spike

**Live example:** 
http://webforms-fun.azurewebsites.net/   with XDT transform

**Our rewrite rule:**

```
<rule name="CDN Host Header Rewrite" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{HTTP_X_CF_ORIGIN}" pattern="(.+)" />
  </conditions>
  <serverVariables>
    <set name="HTTP_HOST" value="{C:1}" />
  </serverVariables>    
  <action type="None" />
</rule>
```

**Our XDT Transform:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <rewrite>
            <allowedServerVariables>
            <add name="HTTP_HOST" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
            </allowedServerVariables>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**applicationHost (found via [IIS Manager](https://www.siteextensions.net/packages/IISManager/)):**

```
<rewrite>
  <allowedServerVariables>
    <add name="HTTP_HOST" />
  </allowedServerVariables>
  <globalRules />
  <outboundRules />
  <providers />
  <rewriteMaps />
  <rules />
</rewrite>
```

**Failed Request Tracking:**

[image: Example of header saying it's been updated]

**Testing**

If I create a test rule to prove the HTTP_HOST is being altered, it correctly uses the HTTP_HOST data set via the X-CF-ORIGIN header:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{HTTP_X_CF_ORIGIN}" pattern=".+" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.+)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://some-site.com/{C:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

Please help - what have we missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that Azure doesn't like setting the **HTTP_HOST** server variable. It works correctly if you use the **HTTP_DISGUISED_HOST**

Change this line in the rewrite rule:

```
<set name="HTTP_HOST" value="{C:1}" />
```

to this:

```
<set name="HTTP_DISGUISED_HOST" value="{C:1}" />
```

Change this line in the applicationHost.xdt:

```
<add name="HTTP_HOST" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
```

to this:

```
<add name="HTTP_DISGUISED_HOST" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
```